# Android MediaPlayer seekTo after video finished playing

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I use VideoView with MediaController and MediaPlayer to play an HLS stream (The issue doesn't occur with normal mp4 file).
when the video finishes playing and I try to use a seekbar, I get logcat error: **E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)** and the activity shows **Can't play this video** dialog. How can I prevent that? I've already tried to implement `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` interface like this:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(...));
    videoView.start();
    videoView.pause();
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you really want to do and how your video stream works:

1. If you want to loop the video - because your onCompletion() kinda tries to do that - you can try a more simple approach with `setLooping(true)`
2. Eventually you can improve you error handling to something like:

   ```
   yourPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
           if (mp.isPlaying())
               mp.stop();
           mp.reset();
           mp.play();
           return true;
       }
   });
   ```

Edit:

3. (After feedback from the comments) - if no looping required, but seeking: ultimately it is up to the level Android's MediaPlayer supports HLS (MPEG-TS) seeking [developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) - says 'not seekable'... Probably on more recent Androids where NuPlayer is used, situation could be better.

Comment: I don't want to loop the video. I wan't to be able to seek the video even after it finishes playing (which works for .mp4 file, but not for HLS stream). I tried to fix it by reseting the URI, but that's not a solution.

Comment: I see - then ultimately it is up to the level Android's MediaPlayer supports HLS (MPEG-TS) seeking https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html - says 'not seekable'... Probably on more recent Androids where NuPlayer is used, situation could be better.

Comment: Oh thanks, can you include that in the answer so I can accept it?